AttributeError processing template 'msg.idl.em': AttributeError: module 'em' has no attribute 'BUFFERED_OPT'
When doing colcon build step in RealSense-ROS installation tutorial I face the CMake Error:
AttributeError: module 'em' has no attribute 'BUFFERED_OPT'

In my ros2_ws/src folder I have realsense-ros, vision_opencv, and xacro as the latter 2 caused errors of missing on rosdep install.
The software versions are:

OS: Debian 12
ROS distribution: Jazzy
RealSense SDK: librealsense-2.47.0
RealSense ROS wrapper: realsense-ros 3.2.2
C compiler: GNU 12.2.0
ament_cmake_ros: 0.12.0
Python: 3.11.2
em library: python3-empy 3.3.4-2

The full error log:
user@device:~/ros2_ws $ colcon build
Starting >>> cv_bridge
Starting >>> realsense2_camera_msgs
Starting >>> image_geometry
Starting >>> xacro
--- stderr: realsense2_camera_msgs
CMake Error at /opt/ros/jazzy/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake:57 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3 -m rosidl_adapter --package-name
  realsense2_camera_msgs --arguments-file
  /home/pi/ros2_ws/build/realsense2_camera_msgs/rosidl_adapter__arguments__realsense2_camera_msgs.json
  --output-dir
  /home/pi/ros2_ws/build/realsense2_camera_msgs/rosidl_adapter/realsense2_camera_msgs
  --output-file
  /home/pi/ros2_ws/build/realsense2_camera_msgs/rosidl_adapter/realsense2_camera_msgs.idls)
  returned error code 1:

  AttributeError processing template 'msg.idl.em'

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/resource/__init__.py", line 51, in evaluate_template
      em.BUFFERED_OPT: True,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  AttributeError: module 'em' has no attribute 'BUFFERED_OPT'



  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
    File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
               ^^^^^^
    File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/main.py", line 53, in main
      abs_idl_file = convert_to_idl(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/__init__.py", line 19, in convert_to_idl
      return convert_msg_to_idl(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/msg/__init__.py", line 39, in convert_msg_to_idl
      expand_template('msg.idl.em', data, output_file, encoding='iso-8859-1')
    File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/resource/__init__.py", line 23, in expand_template
      content = evaluate_template(template_name, data)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/resource/__init__.py", line 69, in evaluate_template
      _interpreter.shutdown()
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shutdown'

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/jazzy/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:132 (rosidl_adapt_interfaces)
  CMakeLists.txt:22 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)


---
Failed   <<< realsense2_camera_msgs [4.00s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< xacro [9.19s]
Aborted  <<< image_geometry [1min 3s]
Aborted  <<< cv_bridge [1min 51s]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1min 52s]
  1 package failed: realsense2_camera_msgs
  3 packages aborted: cv_bridge image_geometry xacro
  2 packages had stderr output: realsense2_camera_msgs xacro
  4 packages not processed

I tried:

to update all versions and clean error logs, as descibed here
to uninstall em and install empy instead, as described here, but with apt install python3-*

Nothing worked for me though. Thanks for any help in advance!

Here is the log for command
colcon build --symlink-install --event-handlers console_cohesion+ --continue-on-error

Okay, it turned out that ROS2 didn't work properly, so the earlier steps of the tutorial may be the root of evil. But if there are any ideas other than that, I would appreciate them.
